# How to evaluate the convexity of an optimal control problem?

Tags: convexity, convex-optimization, optimal-control

Can we consider an optimal control problem, a convex optimization problem like static optimization problems? If it is possible, under what conditions, will this problem be a convex problem? For example, in the general problem as follows, how can we check the convexity of the problem (if we arrive to a solution, is it optimal or not)?

$$
\max_{u \in \mathcal{U}} Q(u) = \int_{0}^{T} F(x(t),u(t), t) dt + S(x(T),T) \\
\dot{x}(t)= f(x(t),u(t), t)
$$

Moreover, is it possible to obtain an explicit form for $Q(u)$? When is $Q(u)$ a concave of $u$?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to take a look at "*Foundations of Optimization*" written by Osman Guler and edited by Springer in 2010. The 3rd chapter is wholly dedicated to Variational Principles and in 4.5 "*Optimization on Convex Sets*" is stated that:

> *One of the most important and basic proprieties of convex functions is the fact that any local minimizer on a convex set is a global one.*